# How to find synonyms for some word from other texts

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I was wondering how could I find words that have similar meaning just from lots of texts for example news articles.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [softwarerecs.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about article spinning. Just do a google search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be using word2vec. Train a word2vec on your texts (as a corpus). Then explore near vectors to the vector of the query. Or if you want similar words, cluster all obtained vectors and find meaningful clusters through them.